Lots of packages kept back for over 6 months
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I've got over 300 packages that have been kept back for over six months, seems a long time:
The following upgrades have been deferred due to phasing:
file-roller python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
The following packages have been kept back:
<list of 325 packages>
I cannot identify any one package that may be causing the problem, though not absolutely sure how to do that. I do not want to force any packages to upgrade with the risk of breaking something.
What am I not doing?

Please edit your question and add the output of sudo apt update && sudo upgrade to your question,

Currently (2024-12-31), on my Ubuntu:
$ . /etc/os-release ; echo $PRETTY_NAME
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

$ sudo apt-get upgrade --assume-no
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following upgrades have been deferred due to phasing:
  file-roller python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

For what it is worth, that is after having done the following...
The packages that actually CAN be installed, will be included in an upgrade initiated by:
$ sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade

This MAY though included a "higher level" of changes than just plain updates...
So beware!
